# Selenium How to Automation SessionBox extension windows on chrome

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

when I have to open new tap with SessionBox extension windows I have to try to automate the window with selenium code is simple code put is don't working 
* you need anything else  comment  please

Comment: Are you just trying to open a new tab?

Comment: yes i try open new tab with extention if you dont know what sessionbox do look this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jhxYUGBCL6I

Comment: im done to open the tab but the new tab i open it dont automation with selenium code this my problim

Comment: Use action chains to send CONTROL+TAB to navigate to the next tab.

Comment: Something like this actions = ActionChains(self.driver)      
actions.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).key_down(Keys.TAB).key_up(Keys.TAB).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()

Comment: this doesn't work bro same PROBLEM

Comment: Hello, have you finally found any solution?